# Changing accessoy image works, but I want to change the BOOL value in the plist as well

Tags: iphone, uitableview, plist

I've use the following example for changing an (accessory)image in a UITableViewCell's. It works great. However the code only changes the image, but not the value in the plist.
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/

In the method underneath I would like to save the changed BOOL in the dataList.plist.

```
- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
if (indexPath != nil)
{
[self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
}
```

**What should be the best approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply update the (mutable) data array that you use to populate your table view. When there is a change to the data and you want to persist it, write the entire data array to disk via the standard file manager calls.

Unfortunately, plists can only be read / written all at once.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
*1.So if one value has been changed the whole plist will be re-saved?

*2. Can you please give an example based on the following code: 
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. Please use codereview.stackexchange.com for code reviews. 3. You should accept the answer.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to save the status of a BOOL value then by using a plist?